# Audio Kit - Frequency Modulated Tones at different DB levels?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

Is it possible to generate frequency modulated tones using Audio Kit inside an IOS Application using Swift?

My goal is to have puretones AND frequency modulated tones(also known as "Warble Tones") be played on button press. I have managed to play different puretones at different frequencies although I am struggling to generate a warble tone.

Comment: doc   https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKFMOscillator.html